# Spring Boot : package maven project multi modules

Tags: spring-boot, maven, deployment

I have a maven project with 4 modules and one parent POM.
After "`mvn clean package`", 4 jar files was generated :

```
application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
domain-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
exposition-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
infrastructure-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But, i want deploy this application on tomcar server.
I tried adding this in the parent pom but the package didn't work.

```
<build>
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

I don't know how to get a war file...
Thank you for your help !

**EDIT**

pom.xml for exposition package

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.example.projetfilrouge</groupId>
    <artifactId>profil-skype</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>exposition</artifactId>
   
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example.projetfilrouge</groupId>
            <artifactId>application</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- AOP dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- springfox-swagger2 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring-security-test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DevTools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
          <!-- JWT -->
          <dependency>
              <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
              <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
              <version>0.9.1</version>
          </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Are all of those projects spring-boot projects ? Or only one is a spring boot project and others are libraries ?

Comment: it's one spring boot project with 4 maven project module.

Comment: Does all 4 of them has @SpringBootApplication annotation at one of the class?

Comment: No, only one package : "exposition"; this package contains the RestController and main class with @SpringBootApplication annotation

Comment: Can you share the pom.xml file of the exposition module ?

Comment: yes, i added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as I understand , you have a maven project with 4 modules. Only one of them `exposition` is a `Spring Boot Application` , others may be internal library projects.

You need to change your `pom.xml` of exposition module.
add

```
<artifactId>exposition</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

This will tell `maven` that you want war packages not Jar.

Now you need to tell `Spring` that you need a `war`. Change you `Application` class (the class with `@SpringBootApplicaiton` annotation like the following.)

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class YourSpringBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(YourSpringBootApplication.class, args);
  }
  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
  }
}
```

This `SpringBootServletInitializer` will configure spring to build an `war.` Now run `mvn clean package` and your exposition module should produce an war. This is the war you need to deploy. Copy the war and deploy it to tomcat.